# Security voter on relational entity field when not using custom subresource path

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have started doing some more advanced security things in our application, where companies can create their own user roles with customizable CRUD for every module, which means you can create a custom role "Users read only" where you set "read" to "2" and create, update, delete to 0 for the user module. And the same for the teams module.

- 0 means that he have no access at all.
- 1 means can access **all** data under company,
- 2 means can access only things related to him (if he is owner
  of an another user),

Which should result in the behavior that, when user requests a team over a get request, it returns the team with the users that are in the team, BUT, since the user role is configured with `$capabilities["users"]["read"] = 2`, then `team.users` should contain only him, without the other team members, because user cannot see users except himself and users that he created.

So far I have managed to limit collection-get operations with a doctrine extension that implements `QueryCollectionExtensionInterface` and filters out what results to return to the user:

- when I query with a role that has `$capabilities["teams"]["read"] = 2` then the collection returns only teams that user is part of, or teams that he created.
- when I query for users with role that has `$capabilities["teams"]["read"] = 1` then it returns all teams inside the company. Which is correct.

The problem comes when I query a single team. For security on item operations I use Voters, which checks the user capabilities before getting/updating/inserting/... a new entity to the DB, which works fine.

So the problem is, that when the team is returned, the user list from the manytomany user<->team relation, contains all the users that are part of the team. I need to somehow filter out this to match my role capabilities. So in this case if the user has `$capabilities["users"]["read"] = 2`, then the `team.users` should contain only the user making the request, because he has access to list the teams he is in, but he has no permission to view other users than himself.

So my question is, how can add a security voter on relational fields for item-operations and collection-operations.

A rough visual representation of what I want to achieve

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="teams")
     * @Groups({"team.read","form.read"})
     * @Security({itemOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('user.view', object)",
 *              "access_control_message"="Access denied."
 *          },
 *         "put"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('user.update', object)",
 *              "access_control_message"="Access denied."
 *          },
 *         "delete"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('user.delete', object)",
 *              "access_control_message"="Access denied."
 *          },
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('user.list', object)",
 *              "access_control_message"="Access denied."
 *          },
 *          "post"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('user.create', object)",
 *              "access_control_message"="Access denied."
 *          },
 *      }})
     */
    private $users;
```

I don't think Normalizer is a good solution from a performance perspective, considering that the DB query was already made.

Comment: You say that your GET collection operation behaves as expected thank to a Doctrine Extension. Why don't you implements a `QueryItemExtensionInterface` to your item GET operation as well ? Do collection and item GET operation share the same serialization group ?

Comment: @rugolinifr yes I am implementing QueryItemExtensionInterace as well. It triggers before the Voter, so if something is not accessible for the user, then the get-item will end up with not found message instead of permission denied from the voter. As for the Groups, I haven't skilled it yet really well. On entity Team I have normalizationContext.groups "team.read" on $team.user i have @Groups("team.read") and on entity User I also have normalizationContext.group "team.read" and "user.read". So I guess, they share.

Comment: @rugolinifr if I do the request like /api/teams/XY/users it works as expected, but I would like to keep it under one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, in the end the only problem is that when you make a request `GET /api/teams/{id}`, the property `$users` contains all users belonging to the team, but given user's permissions, you just want to display a subset.

Indeed Doctrine Extensions are not enough because they only limits the number of entities of the targeted entity, i.e `Team` in your case.

But it seems that [Doctrine Filters](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#using-doctrine-orm-filters) cover this use case; they allow to add extra SQL clauses to your queries, even when fetching associated entities. But I never used them myself so I can't be 100% sure. Seems to be a very low level tool.

Otherwise, I deal with a similar use case on my project, but yet I'm not sure it fit all your needs:

- Adding an extra `$members` array property without any `@ORM` annotation,
- Excluding the `$users` association property from serialization, replacing it by `$members`,
- Decorating the data provider of the `Team` entity,
- Making the decorated data provider fill the new property with a restricted set of users.

```php
// src/Entity/Team.php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TeamRepository::class)
 */
class Team
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class)  //This property is persisted but not serialized
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @var User[]  //This property is not persisted but serialized
     * @Groups({read:team, ...})
     */
    private $members = [];
```

```php
// src/DataProvider/TeamDataProvider.php
class TeamDataProvider implements CollectionDataProviderInterface, ItemDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    /** @var ItemDataProvider */
    private $itemDataProvider;

    /** @var CollectionDataProvider*/
    private $collectionDataProvider;

    /** @var Security  */
    private $security;

    public function __construct(ItemDataProvider $itemDataProvider, 
                                CollectionDataProvider $collectionDataProvider,
                                Security $security)
    {
        $this->itemDataProvider = $itemDataProvider;
        $this->collectionDataProvider = $collectionDataProvider;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $resourceClass === Team::class;
    }

    public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        /** @var Team[] $manyTeams */
        $manyTeams = $this->collectionDataProvider->getCollection($resourceClass, $operationName);
        foreach ($manyTeams as $team) {
            $this->fillMembersDependingUserPermissions($team);
        }
        return $manyTeams;
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        /** @var Team|null $team */
        $team = $this->itemDataProvider->getItem($resourceClass, ['id' => $id], $operationName, $context);
        if ($team !== null) {
            $this->fillMembersDependingUserPermissions($team);
        }
        return $team;
    }

    private function fillMembersDependingUserPermissions(Team $team): void
    {
        $currentUser = $this->security->getUser();
        if ($currentUser->getCapabilities()['users']['read'] === 2) {
            $team->setMembers([$currentUser]);
        } elseif ($currentUser->getCapabilities()['users']['read'] === 1) {
            $members = $team->getUsers()->getValues();
            $team->setMembers($members);  //Current user is already within the collection
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT AFTER REPLY**

The constructor of the `TeamDataProvider` use concrete classes instead of interfaces because it is meant to decorate *precisely* ORM data providers. I just forgot that those services use aliases. You need to configure a bit:

```yaml
#  config/services.yaml

App\DataProvider\TeamDataProvider:
    arguments:
        $itemDataProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.default.item_data_provider'
        $collectionDataProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.default.collection_data_provider'
```

This way you keep advantages of your extensions.

Comment: Are you god? That's one of the best explained answers I have ever seen. Yes, that's exactly what I need. As soon I will get to work on the project I will try it. How can I repay you for your time?

Comment: Just let me know what solution you eventually have implemented

Comment: Okay, so I have tried it out but I needed to change few things (ex.: in constructor instead of ItemDataProvider to use ItemDataProviderInterface since I don't have that class available). The code fires but it goes rampage on memory when temDataProvider->getItem or itemDataProvider->getCollection is called. So I was digging around in API platform documentation, where it says to use "SerializerAwareDataProviderInterface" in case of CircularReferenceException, that does not help. I guess it still goes circular.

Comment: I have solved the memory issue in the getItem by using 

$manager = $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass($resourceClass);
$team = $manager->find($resourceClass, $id);

instead of itemDataProvider, which is not great, but it kind of works. When I use same approach for collection, then it returns all teams since the rules specified in CurrentUserExtension stops working, since it's new separate query.

Comment: I have edited my response to solve your circular reference issue. I use the `bin/console debug:container | less` command to find aliases of `ItemDataProvider` and `CollectionDataProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Meanwhile I have figured it out a different way to overcome the circural reference while maintaining the CurrentUserExtension, by creating a query builder in the getCollection, where I apply the extension and then loop through the teams and set the members (honestly I feel like a genius :D). Your way seems more "integrated" with less coding, so I will go with the way you suggested in your edit. Thank you again, I have learned so much